# Which driver should I choose?

Tags: drivers, ati

I have to play 720p/1080p videos and I want to play games, so I need the best I can get.

In Software Sources, under Additional Drivers, these are my options:

- using x.org x server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source)
- using video driver for the amd graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)
- using video driver for the amd graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)

Answer (score 2):

The best option: FGLRX - Proprietary drivers, downloaded directly from ATI and compiled yourself!

In addition to obysr's answer, I always had trouble installing using the Additional Drivers. Below are a bunch of commands I used to build and install the drivers directly from the AMD website.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6;
sudo apt-get install dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases;
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-core libgcc1;
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32gcc1 libc6-i386;
cd /usr ; sudo ln -svT lib /usr/lib64;
cd ~/; mkdir catalyst12.4; cd catalyst12.4/
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.zip;
unzip ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run;
sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise;
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb;
```

- Copy and paste these into a file.
- Save as installATI without an extension on your Desktop (important!).
- Right click on the file and select properties.
- Select the 'Permissions' tab and tick the 'Allow executing as a program' textbox.
- Close that window.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal.
- Type `sudo ./Desktop/installATI` and enter your password

Comment: So did I, additional driver makes my screen get blank

Answer (score 1):

Second Option, FGLRX. it's stable version of original AMD Radeon driver. the fglx-updates too, it's newest update version of original AMD Radeon driver, but doesn't guarantee it will be stable with your Ubuntu